# Get percent code coverage with FxCop

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, fxcop

I am currently trying to write a unit test library for a code base in C#. I want to view the percent code coverage my tests are achieving. I am using VS2010 which does not have any build in code analysis tools. I have downloaded FxCop and included it at an external tool in VS2010, but I don't know how to get the code coverage percentage. I believe it would be done by setting rules for that, but I am not sure. I have looked into the rule sets and how to create custom rules, but I am not sure how to implement it or what rule set libraries I would use.

I am completely new to FxCop and external analysis tools in general, so a step by step or any direction you can give would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know FxCop, any version even the newest CodeAnalysis 2017, doesn't import code coverage data.

You can try the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). It can [import code coverage data](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-coverage) from VisualStudio coverage, NCover and dotCover. Then you can harness this code coverage data in a number of way:

- Write a rule that checks that all classes with a certain attribute (like an attribute named FullCoveredAttribute) are 100% covered
- Write a rule that checks that all classes that were 100% covered at the baseline, are still 100% covered (NDepend has the notion of [baseline](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-diff-in-visual-studio) to check evolution)
- Write a rule to compare code coverage with various other code metrics, like [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#CC), it is recommended that complex classes and methods gets 100% covered
- Visualize Code Coverage data with the [metric view](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/treemap-visualization-of-code-metrics) based on colored treemaping. In the screenshot below, small rectangle are methods. The area is proportional to #lines of code and the color depends on the % code coverage (green = 100% yellow = 80% red = 0%)

[image: NDepend metric treemap colored code coverage]

Answer (score -1):

Code coverage implies running instrumented code and gathering statistics about which code paths are being executed. FxCop is a static analysis tool. You have an instance of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I understand I was misguided with my question and the path I was attempting to take for my solution. Instead of telling me how wrong I was with the question I was asking, it would have been far more productive to say either that I needed to try a different tool, or guide me in the correct direction since you clearly understood what I was looking to do. Please try to keep comments to comments instead of answers.